# Convert date format with time to millisec

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts

I have the date format: `"2015-09-28T10:15:00.000Z"`.

In Highstocks I have the structure:

```
[
  [date, value], ["2015-09-28T10:15:00.000Z", 1080]
]
```

How do I convert the dateformat to millisec, so that Hightocks can read it?

The other questions didn´t lead me to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date.prototype.getTime()` returns the time in milliseconds.

```
millisec = new Date("2015-09-28T10:15:00.000Z").getTime();
```

The result is: `1443435300000`